# SVN: Recursive add

Tags: svn

I am trying add new project files in a SVN folder from my working copy freshly. Its asking an option "Recursive" with a message "Are you sure you want to add *** many items?" . Could someone guide me what is the use of this "Recursive" option to enable? Should i have enable it when i'm freshly adding new project files or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 95):

Short version: **svn add * --force** is all you need

Long version:
According to [svn add](http://svn.gnu.org.ua/svnbook/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html) manual page

Normally, the command svn add * will skip over any directories that are already under version control. Sometimes, however, you may want to add every unversioned object in your working copy, including those hiding deeper down. Passing the --force option makes svn add recurse into versioned directories:

```
$ svn add * --force
A         foo.c
A         somedir/bar.c
A         otherdir/docs/baz.doc
```

Comment: For me it just did the files in the current directory, so I did the same for `*/*` and `*/*/*` and `*/*/*/*` etc... and it worked.
Nasty, but working :)
thanks

Comment: It does not take into account the ignore properties.

Comment: It only works without the asterisk alone. If you try to specify somewhat like *.c for example, it does not work. (I am just adding a note, i think the purposed answer is correct and should be accepted.)

Comment: If the above command fails try adding `--no-auto-props` to the command

Comment: This adds all the files that I have ignored, like compilation output. There has to be a better way...

Comment: If it fails for some sub directories: check if the subdirectory contains a separate .svn folder (directory is an separate, external svn repository). Manually adding that directory will also fail with following exemplary (German) error message:
root@server:/tmp/svn-folders-copy# svn add etc/nginx
svn: Warnung: W150002: »/tmp/svn-folders-copy/etc/nginx« befindet sich bereits unter Versionskontrolle
svn: E200009: Konnte nicht alle Ziele hinzufügen, da einige Ziele schon versioniert sind
svn: E200009: Ungültiges Ziel für die angeforderte Operation

Answer (score 10):

First to answer your question if you should enable the recursive option:
If you have copied a folder structure with multiple files and nested folders inside, the recursive add is something you need.

In command line, this should work for you:

```
svn add * --depth infinity
```

If it does not work, you can try to use the '--force' argument:

```
svn add * --force --depth infinity
```

Or, in some cases where the ignore properties are making troubles, you might also need to use '--no-ignore' to succeed:

```
svn add * --force --no-ignore --depth infinity
```

Answer (score 1):

`svn add * --force` did not work for me when adding zip files.

Instead I had to `cd` to the directory containing the zip files and run `svn add .`

```
$ svn add .
A         .
A  (bin)  SOAPUI_TEST_1.zip
A  (bin)  SOAPUI_TEST_2.zip
A  (bin)  SOAPUI_TEST_3.zip
A  (bin)  SOAPUI_TEST_4.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to resort to using our old friend `find` as follows:

`cd root_folder_I_want_to_checkin`

Add folders recursively:

`find . -type d -exec svn add {} \;`

Check status (all should show as `A`):

`svn status`

Some files still showed with status `?` so I did this as well:

`find . -type f -exec svn add {} \;`

Now `svn status` shows all are `A`, so now:

`svn commit . -m 'blah blah blah.'`