# Include all subdirectories when adding using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I force TortoiseSVN to always add new subdirectories and folders when using the `TortoiseSVN > Add...` context menu?  From time to time TortoiseSVN will simply **not** add new subdirectories, or files in the subdirectories, unless I repeatedly click the menu command multiple times.  Each click causes TortoiseSVN to include the next level of items.  Not sure if this is a setting, a bug, or user error.

Environment:
TortoiseSVN v1.9.1, Build 26747 - 64 Bit
Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible with your version of TortoiseSVN, you will have to do it using command line. It's pretty easy and you can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642736/svn-recursive-add).

Here's how it looks like:

```
svn add * --force
```

However, it does not care about ignored files. If you absolutely need to add everything but ignored files, you can use this linux command:

```
svn st –ignore-externals | grep ^? | sed ‘s/\?/svn add/‘ | sh
```

I haven't found this trick on windows. Alternatively, I recommend using git instead.

Answer (score -3):

- Don't use TSVN 1.9.(0|1), it's terrible buggy due to underlying Subversion 1.9
- Don't use `Add` command (for any version and use-case), all new not ignored files are present and visible in commit dialogue, where you have fast and easy selection

**Resume:** Yes, it's pure user-error

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.9.2 is OK.

Comment: Why would I NOT use the Add command?  It's easier than scrolling through the Commit dialog.

Comment: I was waiting for the answer to explain me how to do it instead of saying "don't use this feature". Lets continue Googling then...

Comment: *where you have fast and easy selection* Maybe on your 5 files repo, not on my 20k files one.